# How can I get a User input and add it in a url and open the url in a new tab?

Tags: javascript, html, web

I know nothing about it.
I need to make a simple website.

I will take an input from user.
Suppose the input is 'LOL'
Then I need to open a new tab with this url - "https://www.help.me/LOL"

#Help me Please

Comment: Could you please share what have tried so far to achieve this? Read this to understand how to ask a good question https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Without sharing your code and your programming language more specifically , it is impossible for other users to answer your question. Please tell what you have tried and then you could get an answer. Also, stack overflow says that you shouldn't ask general questions or questions that asks the replier to implement a whole idea.

Answer (score -2):

You can do it by using django forms
In your project directory in views.py file you can use this code

```
from django import forms
from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect

    
class inputform(forms.Form):
    inputfield = forms.CharField(label="Input")

def index(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        x = inputform(request.POST)
        if x.is_valid():
            y = x.cleaned_data["inputfield"]
            return 
            HttpResponseRedirect(f"https://www.help.me/{y}")
    return render(request, "index.html", { "form": 
        inputform() }
```

In HTML, you can write the following code to represent the Input Field in HTML page

in index.html;

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <title> xyz </title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <form method="POST">
      {% csrf_token %}
      {{form}}
      <input type="submit">
    </form>
  </body>
</html>
```

By this you will get your desired results

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow Ahmed. Sowmik has not pointed out which framework or programming language is used. So, your answer may not be helpful as you have provided a code in Django.

Comment: Its was a general help if he knows django and html. Otherwise it could be helpful for other users it wont harm anyone